# java 11 spring boot2 redis runtime exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I migrate from java 8 to java 11, the compilation goes well,
but when running the spring boot 2 application with a version jedis 3.0.0,

I have the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getJedisConnectionFactory' defined in class resource path [/cache/configuration/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'getJedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis / clients / util / Pool
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:591)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda $ doGetBean $ 0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer $ BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference (ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:396)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer $ BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept (ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:368)
        cache.configuration.RedisConfig $$ EnhancerBySpringCGLIB $$ e85c6eec.getJedisConnectionFactory (<generated>)
        at configuration.RedisConfig.redisTemplate (RedisConfig.java:30)
        at cache.configuration.RedisConfig $$ EnhancerBySpringCGLIB $$ e85c6eec.CGLIB $ redisTemplate $ 3 (<generated>)
        cache.configuration.RedisConfig $$ EnhancerBySpringCGLIB $$ e85c6eec $$ FastClassBySpringCGLIB $$ a6f08934.invoke (<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper (MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer $ BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept (ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365)
        at cache.configuration.RedisConfig $$ EnhancerBySpringCGLIB $$ e85c6eec.redisTemplate (<generated>)
        at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base / java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate (SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'getJedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis / clients / util / Pool
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate (SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:583)
        ... 138 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis / clients / util / Pool
        at cache.configuration.RedisConfig.getJedisConnectionFactory (RedisConfig.java:55)
        at cache.configuration.RedisConfig $$ EnhancerBySpringCGLIB $$ e85c6eec.CGLIB $ getJedisConnectionFactory $ 0 (<generated>)
        at cache.configuration.RedisConfig $$ EnhancerBySpringCGLIB $$ e85c6eec $$ FastClassBySpringCGLIB $$ a6f08934.invoke (<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper (MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer $ BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept (ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365)
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 2 is compatible with Jedis 2.9 so you won't be able to use 3.0.0.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions for more info.